# How to determine why my code is not working?

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports Kerry_Sales_Project

' base class
Public Class Bonus
    Public Property SalesId As String
    Public Property Sales As Double


    ' default constructor
    Public Sub New()
        _SalesId = String.Empty
        _Sales = 0
    End Sub


    ' parameterized constructor
    Public Sub New(ByVal strId As String, ByVal dblSold As Double)
        SalesId = strId
        Sales = dblSold
    End Sub


    ' GetBonus method
    Public Overridable Function GetBonus() As Double
        Return _Sales * 0.05
    End Function

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(v As PremiumBonus) As Bonus
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Operator
End Class


' derived class
Public Class PremiumBonus
    Public Property Sales As Double
    Public Property strId As String

    ' default constructor
    Public Sub New(strId As String)
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub


    ' parameterized constructor
    Public Sub New(ByVal strId As String, ByVal dblSold As Double)
        MyBase.New(strId, dblSold)
    End Sub


    ' class method
    Public Overrides Function GetBonus() As Double
        Return MyBase.GetBonus() + (Sales - 2500) * 0.01
    End Function

End Class
```

[image]

Comment: You are missing _Inherits Bonus_ just after the declaration of PremiumBonus

Comment: The class labelled “derived class” doesn’t inherit from anything. Please post the error messages as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In effect, you forgot to place Inherits Bonus in the Premium Bonus class. It would be something like

```
Public Class PremiumBonus: Inherits Bonus
```

And the other thing is the CType operator overload.

```
 Public Shared Widening Operator CType(v As PremiumBonus) As Bonus
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
 End Operator
```

This operator overload is not necessary because the PremiumBonus class is a child of Bunus and they are contained.